# documentdb error creating request message

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to write little pre-insert trigger ( to generate numeric ids for each document in collection ), register it and run using DocumentDB .NET SDK. I'm using DocumentDB emulator to test my code

```
function generateNumericId() {
var counterDocumentId = 'numericIdCounter';
var counterDocumentLink = __.getSelfLink() + 'docs/' + counterDocumentId;
__.readDocument(counterDocumentLink, {},
    function(err, counterDocument) {
        if (err) throw new Error("Can't find counterDocument!");
        counterDocument.value += 1;
        __.upsertDocument(counterDocumentLink, counterDocument);
        var docToCreate = __.request.getBody();
        docToCreate.id = counterDocument.value.toString();
        __.request.setBody(docToCreate);
    });}
```

My .net code registers it sucessfully but when i'm running insert operation
it fails with "Error creating request message" exception. So, please, tell me what is wrong with my code? 
(!IMPORTANT : I already have numericIdCounter document inside the collection, js code fails at readDocument function!)

Comment: ``js code fails at readDocument function`` Please try to log error details to a field of **docToCreate** and check if could find useful info from error.

Comment: but `__.readDocument` don't even runs the callback, so how can i log a details inside of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st mistake : `__.getSelfLink()` => `__.getAltLink()` because `getSelfLink()` provides path built from internal `_id` fields (it's not ok for us - we know only counter `id`, not internal `_id`). `getAltLink()` allows us to build urls like the following : `dbs/mydb/colls/mycoll/docs/numericIdCounter` instead of `dbs/dLIxAA==/colls/dLIxAOFiYAA=/docs/dLIxAOFiYAABAAAAAAAAAA==/`.

The 2nd mistake : `__.upsertDocument(counterDocumentLink, counterDocument);` => `__.upsertDocument(__.getAltLink(), counterDocument);` just after checking api documentation.

Comment: Great answer! Solved my problem. Unfortunately there is hardly any documentation or examples around this.